# Handling errors in Razor Pages ASP.NET Core 3.1 ConfigureServices services.AddDbContext<..>(..) method

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

Our SQL Server would be down once in a while resulting in a http status code 500 error page.  We're using Razor Pages/ASP.NET Core 3.1.  Is it possible to gracefully capture this error and still display the page that pulls data from database (need to do this regardless of production or development environment)? The page uses DI to access database via AddDbContext<..>(..) in ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs. Another question is does the razor pages app connect to SQL Server by calling AddDbContext(..) or is it done in CreateModel OnGet method?  I tried _context.Database.CanConnect() inside the OnGet method but where to capture the exception thrown?

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddDbContext<SampleContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SampleContext")));

    }

    public class CreateModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly SampleContext _context;

        public CreateModel(SampleContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {   
            //if (_context.Database.CanConnect() == false)
            //    throw new Exception("Cannot connect to SQL Server.");

            var x = _context...
            return Page();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you share more details or renderings of the expected result? _does the razor pages app connect to SQL Server by calling AddDbContext(..) or is it done in CreateModel OnGet method?_  It's connected by AddDbContext() , and it also can be done in the `OnConfiguring` method of SampleContext , refer to [Configuring a DbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext) .

Comment: @Xueli Chen - Expected result would be allowing visitors to go to any page and see static content and no content from db instead of being redirected to a http 500 error page when db server is down.  Seems like DI is not the way to go for this?